# Save Python data-frame as Table in Teradata

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, teradata

I want to pull a table from Teradata as a Python data-frame. I know how to accomplish this step. Next I want to run algorithms on the data to transform it however I want. Once I am done with manipulating the data in Python, I want the resulting data-frame to be saved as a new table in Teradata so that I can perform joins with other tables in the database. My question is how do I save a python data-frame back into a database, I would like to do this inside of python using a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [`fastterdata`](https://github.com/mark-hoffmann/fastteradata), specifically the `load_table` function:

```
load_table(abs_path, df, table_name, env, db, connector = "teradata", clear_table=True)

Loads a pandas dataframe from memory into teradata via the optimized fastload functionality.
```

Note that you need to install requirements listed [here](https://github.com/mark-hoffmann/fastteradata#requirements).

Answer (score 2):

although I never performed it by my self, but in theory each of following looks promising:

- SQL Alchemy for Teradata (https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-sqlalchemy-introduction)
- pandas.to_sql (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql)
- above fasterdata (please note that fast load don't exist for MacOS)
- write to csv and Teradata Parallel Transporter the easy way with tdload